# Moving an f-curve from an object to a bone

Tags: animation, nla-editor, dopesheet, graph-editor

I'm altering some animations from direct animations on the object to animations on the bone that influences the object.
I've appended the action to the .blend from the original .blend and applied it to the armature. However, I want the f-curves in the action to apply to one of the bones in the armature, not the armature itself. The only way I've found to move the data is to insert keyframes on the bone then copy the keyframes in the graph editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. The workflow would be:

1. Append the action;
2. Switch to **Dope Sheet** Editor (shortcut is <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>F12</kbd>), then change Editor Mode to **Action Editor**;
3. Select the appended action from the dropdown list in the header, select keys you want, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (or click the second last button at the right-end of the header);
4. Select the target bone in **Pose Mode**, add necessary channels by keying if there isn't any yet. Make sure the cursor is at the expected position, select channels you want to add action on, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste (or click the last button at the right-end of the header). You can also do this step in Graph Editor.

**PS:**

1. The action can be transformed between objects and bones, as long as they got same channel types. However, the result may be not always as expected as you really want.
2. One thing that you should be aware of is the consistency of the rotation mode. For example, if the action for the appended action uses rotation mode as XYZ Euler, and the bone uses Quaternion (WXYZ), then it will fail, either.

Comment: I found to select the keyframes, I had to press "L" to select the all of them for the channel.

Comment: @BenJaguarMarshall That's right. It will speed it up a lot while doing so. Congrats, you got the trick. ;)